# Jupyter Notebook stopped working with errors while accessing .local/share/jupyter/runtime

Tags: permissions, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following message every time I try to start my jupyter notebook. It used to work just fine but I might have messed something up with other installations. Pretty much the **.local/share/jupyter/runtime** folder and **notebook_secret** in jupyter folder aren't accessible and I can't seem to find a solution to that.

```
~$ jupyter notebook
[I 16:25:34.824 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[E 16:25:34.824 NotebookApp] Failed to write cookie secret to /home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret'
[W 16:25:34.824 NotebookApp] Could not set permissions on /home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:61: UserWarning: IPython dir '/home/polina/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(ipdir))
[I 16:25:35.049 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/polina
[I 16:25:35.050 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:25:35.050 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=d0f9d4cec98184cc9ba0f11a19f24bd783176e012ecac56a
[I 16:25:35.050 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=d0f9d4cec98184cc9ba0f11a19f24bd783176e012ecac56a
[I 16:25:35.050 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 16:25:35.050 NotebookApp] Failed to write server-info to /home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4168.json: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4168.json'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1834, in start
    self.write_browser_open_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1752, in write_browser_open_file
    with open(self.browser_open_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/polina/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4168-open.html'
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the permissions on the folder? Have you tried running it with `sudo` or as an administrator?

Comment: @Burgi, yes, `sudo ... --allow-root` helped

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python) on our sister site [so]?